# Is there a faster way to set cell values with VBA than FOR EACH

Tags: excel, vba

At times this range can be tens of thousands of rows for the validation. Currently, in order to set the validation to the correct value for the selection, I am doing a For Each. The following is part of the code where the validation is set.

```
With BCS.Range("AT2:AT" & Lrow).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=BStr
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With

BCS.Range("AT2:AT" & Lrow).Value = "1"  

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("est_temp").Range("A1:A" & Lrow2).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("B_C_I").Range("AO2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("est_temp").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

If Lrow > 2 Then
    For Each c In BCS.Range("AO2:AO" & Lrow)
        With c
            If c.Value = "AA" Then
                Range("AT" & c.Row).Value = "Std % 1"
            ElseIf c.Value = "BB" Then
                Range("AT" & c.Row).Value = "Std % 2"
            Else
                Range("AT" & c.Row).Value = "1"
            End If
        End With
    Next c
End If
```

For obvious reasons when you have to go through 25000+ rows that takes quite some time. Is there a faster way to do this than the For Each?

Comment: Use arrays. Load the AO data into one in one hit, create another the same size, populate the second based on the first, then write it back to AT in one go. You could also use `EVALUATE` with a formula string to achieve it directly.

Comment: How is the code being run/triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rory notes - this will be faster:

```vb
Dim arr, r As Long

If Lrow > 2 Then
    arr = BCS.Range("AO2:AO" & Lrow).Value 'get all the data in an array
    For r = 1 to UBound(arr, 1)
        Select Case arr(r, 1)
            Case "AA": arr(r, 1) = "Std % 1"
            Case "BB": arr(r, 1) = "Std % 2"
            Case Else: arr(r, 1) = "1"
        End Select
    Next r
    BCS.Range("TO2:TO" & Lrow).Value = arr 'write back to sheet
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, brilliant as usual!